# Python Curve_Fit Exponential / Power / Log Curve - Improve Results

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, logistic-regression, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit this data which is asymptotically approaching zero (but never reaching it).

I believe the best curve is an Inverse Logistic Function, but open to suggestions. The Key is the decaying "S-curve" shape which is expected.

Here is the code I have so far, and the plot image below, which is a pretty ugly fit.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# DATA

x = pd.Series([1,1,264,882,913,1095,1156,1217,1234,1261,1278,1460,1490,1490,1521,1578,1612,1612,1668,1702,1704,1735,1793,2024,2039,2313,2313,2558,2558,2617,2617,2708,2739,2770,2770,2831,2861,2892,2892,2892,2892,2892,2923,2923,2951,2951,2982,2982,3012,3012,3012,3012,3012,3012,3012,3073,3073,3073,3104,3104,3104,3104,3135,3135,3135,3135,3165,3165,3165,3165,3165,3196,3196,3196,3226,3226,3257,3316,3347,3347,3347,3347,3377,3377,3438,3469,3469]).values
y = pd.Series([1000,600,558.659217877095,400,300,100,7.75,6,8.54,6.66666666666667,7.14,1.1001100110011,1.12,0.89,1,2,0.666666666666667,0.77,1.12612612612613,0.7,0.664010624169987,0.65,0.51,0.445037828215398,0.27,0.1,0.26,0.1,0.1,0.13,0.16,0.1,0.13,0.1,0.12,0.1,0.13,0.14,0.14,0.17,0.11,0.15,0.09,0.1,0.26,0.16,0.09,0.09,0.05,0.09,0.09,0.1,0.1,0.11,0.11,0.09,0.09,0.11,0.08,0.09,0.09,0.1,0.06,0.07,0.07,0.09,0.05,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.08,0.07,0.1,0.08,0.08,0.05,0.06,0.04,0.04,0.05,0.05,0.04,0.06,0.05,0.05,0.06]).values

# Inverse Logistic Function 
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function
def func(x, L ,x0, k, b):
    y = 1/(L / (1 + np.exp(-k*(x-x0)))+b)
    return y

# FIT DATA

p0 = [max(y), np.median(x),1,min(y)] # this is an mandatory initial guess
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y,p0, method='dogbox',maxfev=10000)

# PERFORMANCE

modelPredictions = func(x, *popt)
absError = modelPredictions - y
SE = np.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = np.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = np.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (np.var(absError) / np.var(y))

print('Parameters:', popt)
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

#PLOT

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'ko', label="Original Noised Data")
plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'r-', label="Fitted Curve")
plt.legend()
plt.yscale('log')
#plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Here is the result when this code is run... and what I would Like to achieve!

[image]

How can I better optimize the curve_fit, so that instead of the code generated RED line, I get something closer to the BLUE drawn line?

Thank you!!

Comment: This looks like something you want to run polynomial regression for (cubic, in this case), rather than logistic regression.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for the tip! Any suggestions where I can get an example or sample code for that?  Thank you!

Comment: have a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html, should get you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

From your plot of data and expected fit, I would guess that you do not really want to model your data `y` as a logistic-like step function but **`log(y)`** as a logistic-like step function.

So, I think you would probably want to use a logistic step function, perhaps adding a linear component to model the log of this data.  I would do this with `lmfit`, as it comes with the models built-in, gives better reporting of resulting, and allows you to greatly simplify your fitting code as with (disclaimer: I am a lead author):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

from lmfit.models import StepModel, LinearModel

# DATA
x = pd.Series([1, 1, 264, 882, 913, 1095, 1156, 1217, 1234, 1261, 1278,
              1460, 1490, 1490, 1521, 1578, 1612, 1612, 1668, 1702, 1704,
              1735, 1793, 2024, 2039, 2313, 2313, 2558, 2558, 2617, 2617,
              2708, 2739, 2770, 2770, 2831, 2861, 2892, 2892, 2892, 2892,
              2892, 2923, 2923, 2951, 2951, 2982, 2982, 3012, 3012, 3012,
              3012, 3012, 3012, 3012, 3073, 3073, 3073, 3104, 3104, 3104,
              3104, 3135, 3135, 3135, 3135, 3165, 3165, 3165, 3165, 3165,
              3196, 3196, 3196, 3226, 3226, 3257, 3316, 3347, 3347, 3347,
              3347, 3377, 3377, 3438, 3469, 3469]).values

y = pd.Series([1000, 600, 558.659217877095, 400, 300, 100, 7.75, 6, 8.54,
              6.66666666666667, 7.14, 1.1001100110011, 1.12, 0.89, 1, 2,
              0.666666666666667, 0.77, 1.12612612612613, 0.7,
              0.664010624169987, 0.65, 0.51, 0.445037828215398, 0.27, 0.1,
              0.26, 0.1, 0.1, 0.13, 0.16, 0.1, 0.13, 0.1, 0.12, 0.1, 0.13,
              0.14, 0.14, 0.17, 0.11, 0.15, 0.09, 0.1, 0.26, 0.16, 0.09,
              0.09, 0.05, 0.09, 0.09, 0.1, 0.1, 0.11, 0.11, 0.09, 0.09,
              0.11, 0.08, 0.09, 0.09, 0.1, 0.06, 0.07, 0.07, 0.09, 0.05,
              0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.08, 0.07, 0.1, 0.08, 0.08, 0.05,
              0.06, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.04, 0.06, 0.05, 0.05, 0.06]).values

model = StepModel(form='logistic') + LinearModel()
params = model.make_params(amplitude=-5, center=1000, sigma=100, intercept=0, slope=0)

result = model.fit(np.log(y), params, x=x)

print(result.fit_report())

plt.plot(x, y, 'ko', label="Original Noised Data")
plt.plot(x, np.exp(result.best_fit), 'r-', label="Fitted Curve")
plt.legend()
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

That will print out a report with fit statistics and best-fit values of:

```
[[Model]]
    (Model(step, form='logistic') + Model(linear))
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 73
    # data points      = 87
    # variables        = 5
    chi-square         = 9.38961801
    reduced chi-square = 0.11450754
    Akaike info crit   = -183.688405
    Bayesian info crit = -171.358865
[[Variables]]
    amplitude: -4.89008796 +/- 0.29600969 (6.05%) (init = -5)
    center:     1180.65823 +/- 15.2836422 (1.29%) (init = 1000)
    sigma:      94.0317580 +/- 18.5328976 (19.71%) (init = 100)
    slope:     -0.00147861 +/- 8.1151e-05 (5.49%) (init = 0)
    intercept:  6.95177838 +/- 0.17170849 (2.47%) (init = 0)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(amplitude, slope)     = -0.798
    C(amplitude, sigma)     = -0.649
    C(amplitude, intercept) = -0.605
    C(center, intercept)    = -0.574
    C(sigma, slope)         =  0.542
    C(sigma, intercept)     =  0.348
    C(center, sigma)        = -0.335
    C(amplitude, center)    =  0.282
```

and produce a plot like this

[image]

You could certainly reproduce all that with `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` if you desired, but I would leave that as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you!  Not sure what the equations are for these formulas though?  I am interested in projecting beyond 3500, so having a formula is important.

Cheers!

Comment: The formula used is the standard logistic function (see https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html#stepmodel) + a line. Lmfit has these models builtin with named parameters to make your life easier.   The model should extend past x=3600 without any problem.  But you certainly can try other models to see which one best fits your data. The most important thing to understand is that you want to fit the Logistic+Line model to the `log(y),` not to `y`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I'd fit a hyperbolic tangent<sup>1</sup> to the base-10 logarithm of your data.

Let's use

log10 *(y) = y₀ - a* tanh *(λ(x-x₀))*

as your function

Approximately your *x* runs from 0 to 3500, your log10(*y*) from 3 to -1, with the provision that tanh(2) = -tanh(2) ≈ 1 we have

*y₀+a = 3, y0-a= -1 ⇒ y₀ = 1, a = 2;*

*λ = (2-(-2)) / (3500-0); x₀ = (3500-0)/2.*

(this rough estimate is necessary to provede `curve_fit` with an initial guess, otherwise the procedure gets lost).

Omitting the boilerplate I have eventually

```
X = np.linspace(0, 3500, 701)
plt.scatter(x, np.log10(y), label='data')
plt.plot(X, 1-2*np.tanh(4/3500*(X-1750)), label='hand fit')
(y0, a, l, x0), *_ = curve_fit(
    lambda x, y0, a, l,x 0: y0 - a*np.tanh(l*(x-x0)),
    x, np.log10(y),
    p0=[1, 2, 4/3500, 3500/2])
plt.plot(X, y0-a*np.tanh(l*(X-x0)), label='curve_fit fit')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

---

Note 1: [the logistic function is the hyperbolic tangent in disguise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#Mathematical_properties)

Answer (score 0):

I see that your plot uses log scaling, and I found that several different sigmoidal equations gave what appear to be good fits to the natural log of the Y data. Here is a graphical Python fitter using the natural log of the Y data with a four-parameter Logistic equation:

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import warnings


xData = numpy.array([1,1,264,882,913,1095,1156,1217,1234,1261,1278,1460,1490,1490,1521,1578,1612,1612,1668,1702,1704,1735,1793,2024,2039,2313,2313,2558,2558,2617,2617,2708,2739,2770,2770,2831,2861,2892,2892,2892,2892,2892,2923,2923,2951,2951,2982,2982,3012,3012,3012,3012,3012,3012,3012,3073,3073,3073,3104,3104,3104,3104,3135,3135,3135,3135,3165,3165,3165,3165,3165,3196,3196,3196,3226,3226,3257,3316,3347,3347,3347,3347,3377,3377,3438,3469,3469], dtype=float)
yData = numpy.array([1000,600,558.659217877095,400,300,100,7.75,6,8.54,6.66666666666667,7.14,1.1001100110011,1.12,0.89,1,2,0.666666666666667,0.77,1.12612612612613,0.7,0.664010624169987,0.65,0.51,0.445037828215398,0.27,0.1,0.26,0.1,0.1,0.13,0.16,0.1,0.13,0.1,0.12,0.1,0.13,0.14,0.14,0.17,0.11,0.15,0.09,0.1,0.26,0.16,0.09,0.09,0.05,0.09,0.09,0.1,0.1,0.11,0.11,0.09,0.09,0.11,0.08,0.09,0.09,0.1,0.06,0.07,0.07,0.09,0.05,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.08,0.07,0.1,0.08,0.08,0.05,0.06,0.04,0.04,0.05,0.05,0.04,0.06,0.05,0.05,0.06], dtype=float)

# fit the natural lpg of the data
yData = numpy.log(yData)

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print "invalid value" warnings during fit
def func(x, a, b, c, d): # Four-Parameter Logistic from zunzun.com
    return d + (a - d) / (1.0 + numpy.power(x / c, b))


# these are the same as the scipy defaults
initialParameters = numpy.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, initialParameters)

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

print('Parameters:', fittedParameters)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Natural Log of Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: This is really good thank you! The fit from 2000 onward could be better though.I think it is moving in the wrong direction in the latest data (3500->) which is an issue.

Comment: I think the curve needs to be steeper at the ends, and not flatten out so much, it this is possible?

Capturing the exponential decline at the 3500 region is important.

I.e. Approaching, but never reaching, zero

Answer (score 0):

`p0 = [max(y), np.median(x),1,min(y)] # this is an mandatory initial guess`

Just to clarify, since this might be your issue, you shouldn't use "1.0" as your initial guess k. You should use `1.0 / (max(x) - min(x))`

If your X's are data that ranges over say, [1200, 8000]. Then, using 1.0 will really struggle converge. You want to use 1/6800 as `k`, so you start off with a normalized [-1, 1] as your initial x-range.

Main reason being, p.exp(4000) will generally fail to evaluate, which will cause python to struggle to fit the function.